# The usage of the word ethereal for taste

Tags: word-usage

Since ethereal can mean "extremely delicate and light", I wonder if it can be used for the taste of particular beverages or food? In a sentence, it'd be like this "The first cup was excellent but the next ethereal". If the use is correct, what does it actually mean with it being ethereal? Like does it say that the taste is delicate?

Comment: If you use it like that, it would mean *heavenly* — as in, out of this world: *The first cup was excellent but the next, heavenly.*

Comment: Using it like that might be okay for a mousse or a parfait.

Comment: Your example sentence needs work because "The first cup was excellent but the next extremely delicate and light" doesn't make sense.  You need more contrast, e.g. "The first cup was good, although leaning towards heavy and dark; the next batch was extremely delicate and light."  / But frankly I wouldn't have the slightest idea what you mean if you used "ethereal."  However, I never understand wine/coffee reviews so you can pretty much write whatever you want in that context, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: In Google Books I see "ethereal taste," for example, used to describe a specific taste dating back to  the 1850's.  Sometimes, e.g., with "agreeable" or with "pungent." It's hard to know what is meant.